Use RxExtensions to aggregate stream of data
I have a play project to learn Rx as it is something I have always wanted to learn and could be useful.
I just can't seem to grasp it like I did Linq.
So I have a stream of data and would like to perform some aggregation on the stream.
Basically, group the source by name, then further group the sub observable data in windows of 3 seconds, using the first item in the group as the reference point.
So I have an accumulated 3 seconds window of data. The data grouped by name.
Then each grouping is further grouped by people with the same amount of money.
This sub group will be aggregated or reduced to have one PersonData object with average age and dollar amount.
Seems mostly straight forward? but I just can't figure it out.
//PersonData to represent object event
class PersonData
{
  public int Age;
  public string Name;
  public DateTime EntryTime;
  public double DollarAmount;
}

The observer object to keep track of reduce
public class Observer<T> : IObserver<T> where T: PersonData
{
    private T _t;
    private int _count = 0;
    private double _dollarAmt;
 
    public void OnNext(T value)
    {
        _t = value; // just replace with last
        _dollarAmt += value.DollarAmount;   
        ++_count;
    }

    public void OnError(Exception error)
    {
    }

    public void OnCompleted()
    {
        _dollarAmt /= _count;
    }
}



class RxObservableSample
{
    List<PersonData> _personSource = new List<PersonData>();
    
    public RxObservableSample()
    {
        //group by name
        // with a discrete window of 3 seconds
        // this is not accurate, I would prefer to use 3 seconds window using the EntryTime as reference point
        //from the grouped observable, aggregate the dollar amount of all PersonData. 
        
        //simple attempt
        var windowedObservable = _personSource.ToObservable().GroupByUntil(x=>x.Name, x.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
        
        
        
    }

}

After the windowedObservable I don't know where to go from there. I can't access the individual data object.
I have tried Aggregate, but it is asking for a seed but the seed should be the first data in the 3 second window which I can't access anyway.
I have tried replacing Bufffer with Window but doesn't matter as I can't access each PersonData.
Any ideas how to understand Rx? Any hint how to proceed?

mmn why was this put to close?

What does "the the timestamp on the event object group the object by name" mean?

A word for the wise - whenever you implement IObserable<T> or IObserver<T> then you are probably doing something wrong.

@Enigmativity my bad I reworded. Hope it's clearer. The stream is grouped by name first. Then the sub stream is partitioned into window of 3 seconds but using the timestamp of the first object in the name grouping as reference point.. However, this causes an issue because it would need a trigger to know when the window expires. So 3 second from the first object, or when 3 second clock time expires.

@Enigmativity interesting.. if I can't implement the interface then I can't see how to implement it. Makes the task more difficult.

It seems to me that you want this query:
IObservable<PersonData> query =
    from xs in source.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    from z in
        from ys in xs.GroupByUntil(x => x.DollarAmount, x => x.Age, x => x.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)))
        from y in ys.Average()
        select new { DollarAmount = ys.Key, Age = y }
    select new PersonData { Name = xs.Key, DollarAmount = z.DollarAmount, Age = z.Age };

Now, a couple of things to note.
Since you're grouping on DollarAmount then it doesn't make sense to get an average because everything in the group has the same value.
To get an average of Age and return a PersonData instance I needed to change Age from int to double.
If either of these are wrong, please let me know.
I created this test data, using the Microsoft.Reactive.Testing NuGet library:
var now = DateTime.Now;

var people = new List<PersonData>
{
    new PersonData { Name = "Joe", Age = 1, EntryTime = now, DollarAmount = 10m },
    new PersonData { Name = "Barry", Age = 2, EntryTime = now, DollarAmount = 10m },
    new PersonData { Name = "Joe", Age = 3, EntryTime = now, DollarAmount = 10m },
    new PersonData { Name = "Barry", Age = 20, EntryTime = now, DollarAmount = 11m },
    new PersonData { Name = "Joe", Age = 4, EntryTime = now, DollarAmount = 10m },
    new PersonData { Name = "Joe", Age = 5, EntryTime = now.AddSeconds(4), DollarAmount = 11m },
};

var ts = new Microsoft.Reactive.Testing.TestScheduler();

var source = ts.CreateHotObservable(
    people
        .Select(p => new Recorded<Notification<PersonData>>(p.EntryTime.Subtract(now).Ticks, System.Reactive.Notification.CreateOnNext<PersonData>(p)))
        .Append(new Recorded<Notification<PersonData>>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8.0).Ticks, System.Reactive.Notification.CreateOnCompleted<PersonData>()))
        .ToArray());

Now I can run the data using this code:
ts.AdvanceBy(1);
ts.AdvanceTo(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0).Ticks);
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
ts.AdvanceTo(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0).Ticks);
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
ts.AdvanceTo(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4.0).Ticks);
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
ts.AdvanceTo(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7.0).Ticks);
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
ts.AdvanceTo(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(9.0).Ticks);

The result I get was this:


I think I came up with something close.
I changed _personSource.ToObserverable() to Subject<PersonData>. Then:
_subs= _source.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Subscribe(
        personsByName =>
        {
            var windowedObservable =
                personsByName.GroupByUntil(x => x.DollarAmount, x => x.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)));
            windowedObservable.Subscribe(x=>
            {
                Observer<T> dlAmtObserver = new Observer<T>();                        
                x.Subscribe(dlAmtObserver);
            });
        });


If you're subscribing inside a subscription, then you're doing something wrong.

This is effectively the same thing without the nested subscribes: from a in _source.GroupBy(x => x.Name) from b in a.GroupByUntil(x => x.DollarAmount, x => x.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))) from c in b select c

I was thinking on WHEN you want result to be available. Like if all items would come in 1 sec to each other, there would be no output? So I decided to have output for all event, but as required older items are discarded. Also as required it's not depending on real life time, so you can date back items.
Program.cs
using RxTest;

new List<PersonData>
{
    new() { Age = 1, EntryTime = DateTime.Now, DollarAmount = 10d },
    new() { Age = 2, EntryTime = DateTime.Now, DollarAmount = 10d },
    new() { Age = 3, EntryTime = DateTime.Now, DollarAmount = 10d },
    new() { Age = 20, EntryTime = DateTime.Now, DollarAmount = 11d },
    new() { Age = 4, EntryTime = DateTime.Now, DollarAmount = 10d },
    new() { Age = 5, EntryTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(4), DollarAmount = 11d },
}
    .MyWindow()
    .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

AggregateResult.cs
internal record AggregateResult(double AvgAge, double DollarAmount);

MyWindow.cs
using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace RxTest;

internal static class ObservableExtensions
{
    internal static IObservable<AggregateResult> MyWindow(this IEnumerable<PersonData> personData)
    {
        var persons = personData.OrderBy(x => x.EntryTime).ToList();
        if (persons.Count == 0)
        {
            return Observable.Empty<AggregateResult>();
        }
        return persons.Window3Sec();
    }

    private static IObservable<AggregateResult> Window3Sec(this List<PersonData> persons)
    {
        var firstAggregate = new Stack<PersonData>();
        firstAggregate.Push(persons[0]);
        return persons[1..].ToObservable().Scan(firstAggregate, (x, y) =>
        {
            while (x.TryPeek(out var firstItem) && firstItem.EntryTime.AddSeconds(3) < y.EntryTime)
            {
                x.Pop();
            }
            x.Push(y);
            // be careful of modifying the already emitted values. Create a copy for output
            return new Stack<PersonData>(x);
        })
        .GroupByDollar();
    }

    private static IObservable<AggregateResult> GroupByDollar(this IObservable<Stack<PersonData>> personData)
    {
        return
            personData
            .Select(x => 
                x.GroupBy(x => x.DollarAmount)
                    .Aggregate<IGrouping<double, PersonData>, IGrouping<double, PersonData>>(null, (x, y) => y)
                )
            .Select(x => new AggregateResult(x.Average(y => y.Age), x.Key));
    }
}

So about the possibility that we insert an event that happened before the last processed event and still calculate it> I think it's like event sourced programming. If you want to do that, you can, but you need to rerun the whole dataset each time an item is older than last one. Rx's hot observables for example are pretty much rely on continuality of new items. If you could just insert a terminating element, that emits onComplete(), what you do? Erase the last elements from the console that was subscribing?
Results:
// first event came
AggregateResult { AvgAge = 1, DollarAmount = 10 }
// second event came, emits the new value for grouped 10 dollar amount, because it's in the 3 s interval. Ages were 1, 2
AggregateResult { AvgAge = 1,3333333333333333, DollarAmount = 10 }
// third event came, emits the new value for grouped 10 dollar amount, because it's in the 3 s interval. Ages were 1, 2, 3
AggregateResult { AvgAge = 1,75, DollarAmount = 10 }
// fourth event came, emits the new value for grouped 11 dollar amount, because it's in the 3 s interval. Age is 20
AggregateResult { AvgAge = 20, DollarAmount = 11 }
// fifth event came, emits the new value for grouped 10 dollar amount, because it's in the 3 s interval. Ages were 1, 2, 3, 4
AggregateResult { AvgAge = 2,2, DollarAmount = 10 }
// 3 seconds passed
// sixth event came, emits the new value for grouped 11 dollar amount, clean slate
AggregateResult { AvgAge = 5, DollarAmount = 11 }

Edit:
While I tried the code it's not the same results as I wrote. I slightly changed the Window3Sec part:
private static IObservable<AggregateResult> Window3Sec(this List<PersonData> persons)
    => persons
    .ToObservable()
    .Scan(new Stack<PersonData>(), (x, y) =>
        {
            while (x.TryPeek(out var firstItem) && firstItem.EntryTime.AddSeconds(3) < y.EntryTime)
            {
                x.Pop();
            }
            x.Push(y);
            return new Stack<PersonData>(x);
        })
    .GroupByDollar();

The new result is more correct:
AggregateResult { AvgAge = 1, DollarAmount = 10 } // avg of [1]
AggregateResult { AvgAge = 1,5, DollarAmount = 10 } // avg of [1, 2]
AggregateResult { AvgAge = 2, DollarAmount = 10 } // avg of [1, 2, 3]
AggregateResult { AvgAge = 20, DollarAmount = 11 }
AggregateResult { AvgAge = 2,5, DollarAmount = 10 } // avg of [1, 2, 3, 4]
AggregateResult { AvgAge = 5, DollarAmount = 11 }

